# most efficient way to sort strings with only 2 distinct characters?

Tags: string, sorting

If I have strings that I know have no more than 2 distinct characters,

example set:

```
aab
abbbbabb
bbbaa
aaaaaaa
aaaa
abab
a
aa
aaaaa
aaabba
aabbbab
```

What's the most efficient way to put them into alphabetical order?

the resulting sorted set:

```
a
aa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaabba
aab
aabbbab
abab
abbbbabb
bbbaa
```

edit:

I know I could just use a normal sorting algorithm (quick sort, merge sort), but the question is: Does the fact that there are not more than 2 distinct characters make something else more efficient?

If the maximum length of the string matters, I would like to know the answer for 2 different scenarios:

1. maximum length of the string is the same as the number of strings (n strings being sorted, n maximum length of the string)
2. maximum length of the string is log n, with n as the number of strings being sorted

I can also assume that all of the strings are distinct.

Comment: Which language? What have you tried?

Comment: What's the maximum length of a string?

Comment: @rcgldr good question - information added to question

Comment: You could convert the strings into binary bits,0's for a's, 1's for b's, but you'd have to keep track of string lengths as a number of bits. Using base 4 (2 bits per character), 0 = no character, 1 = 'a', 2 = 'b', 3 = unused, but make all strings the same length, left justified. You could then use counting / radix sort if the string length wasn't too long.

Answer (score -1):

The String [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [compareToIgnoresCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) method will return a negative integer, 0, or a polsitive integer depending on the alphabetical ordering of the two Strings being compared.  Try that.

Answer (score -1):

General sorting algorithm based on comparisons only asymptotically can't achieve results better than `O(nlogn)`. In your case there is an additional information (2 distinct chars) which has a potential of improving this result. A simple approach that will yield a `O(n)` result:

1. Check the first character (let's mark it `x`).
2. Scan the string till the end

   - whenever `x` is encountered increase a counter.
   - when encountered the non-x character (let's mark it `y`) for the first time store it in a dedicated variable
3. Compare `x` and `y`.
   if `x < y` fill the string from the beginning with `x`'s according to the counter and the rest with `y`
   if `x > y` fill the string from the beginning with `y`'s `string length-num of x`'s slots and the rest with `x`'s.

Comment: That looks like sorting the characters in the strings. I meant sorting the set of strings. (I recognize my example may have made that unclear, so I have edited it.)